# Rails 4 Fragment Caching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, memcached

I'm trying to increase performance for my app so I'm looking into fragment caching.

I'm trying to understand what to cache.  For example, on all pages of my site I display a list of recent articles.

In my application controller I have a filter that sets:

```
@recent_articles = Article.get_recent
```

I have the following in my view/footer:

```
- cache(cache_key_for_recent_articles) do
          %h3 RECENT ARTICLES
          - @recent_articles.each do |article|
            .recent-article
              = link_to add_glyph_to_link("glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right", article.name), article_path(article, recent: true)
          - if Article.count > 4
            = link_to "MORE ARTICLES", articles_path(), class: "btn btn-primary more-articles"
```

My question is. Am I properly caching this?  I'm tailing the logs, but I see a query for the articles so I'm assuming no.  It's not clear to me what this would do when I query in the controller, but cache a section of the page.

Is this a place for low level caching rather than fragment caching?

Thanks.

Comment: You could also cache the recent articles query: `Rails.cache.fetch([cache_keys]) {@recent_articles = Article.get_recent}`

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it right. It might seem silly, because it always has to make the db hit anyway, but the gains can be substantial. Imagine each article had threaded comments, with images. In this case, if you kept the controller the exact same, using the same caching construct would save you a tremendous amount of db effort. So, yeah, if you can pull from memcached instead of running through haml with a bunch of rails helpers (those `link_to`s aren't free) you'll save a bit for sure, but the real gains are found when you can subtly restructure your architecture (as lazy as possible) in order to really take advantage. And that initial hit on Articles? Your db should do a pretty good job of caching that call, I'm not sure you would want to cache it too aggressively, in this case anyway, given the name of the method called.